# Only cached image in Flutter CachedNetworkImage for app session

Tags: flutter, image, caching

Just want to get clarification on below coding. cacheDuration set seconds to 0 caches avatar.jpg for the app session, any subsequent used is getting from cache. Once app is closed, avatar.jpg will be deallocated from cache. Am I right ?

CachedNetworkImage(
imageUrl: 'https://example.com/avatar.jpg',
cacheDuration: const Duration(seconds: 0),
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) use the [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) library to manage cached files. Here is what the [doc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager#when-are-cached-files-removed) says :

> the cache deletes files when there are too many, ordered by last use, and when files just haven't been used for longer than the stale period

So I think your solution with a Duration of 0 will work but you can also try a cleaner solution (I think): try to delete all the cached image at the start of your app (in the `main()` method for exemple).

To clean all cache you can try this (it will remove old cached images):

```
await DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

The image is stored in memory during your session, rather than on your device's disk. It will be removed from the cache once you close the app.

Comment: If I set to 1 week, where does app store cached images ? Can other apps access them ?